# Regex to remove src="*"

Tags: regex

How i can remove

```
src="../assets/default/js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"
```

from this line

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../assets/default/js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js">
```

using regex?

Comment: What regex dialect are you using?

Answer (score 2):

You didn't specify a regular expression dialect, but this one should work in most:

```
src=".*?"
```

Comment: i also think this was the solution but this returns something different.
">        //</script>    \r\n    \r\n    <script type=\"text/javascript\" "

Answer (score 1):

Though I need to preface this with [the usual disclaimer about parsing HTML with regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454), the following should work for input strings very similar to the example you gave:

```
/src=(["']).*?\1/
```

You didn't say what regex language you're using, but replace whatever matches the above pattern with an empty string.

The main advantage of this version is that it will accept both `src="..."` and `src='...'`, but not `src="...'` or `src='..."`. It also won't be thrown off by stuff like `src="...foo='bar'..."`, although that's unlikely to come up.

Comment: You probably don't want to be using a greedy `.*`

Answer (score 1):

If you're doing this to prevent linking to external scripts, don't. It won't work.

- The inline script can easily inject a new script tag, or otherwise load an external script.
- No sane regexp will handle all the variations of character encodings, multiple `src="…"` attributes (legal according to the spec? I doubt it; does it work? I bet), browser parsing bugs, etc.
- No regexp can handle things like matching quotes correctly.

You'll get to look forward to:

```
<!-- this is even in-spec, except for the made-up attributes fakeout and oops.
     a trivial out-of-spec bit of fun: what happens if we drop the final quote?
     I bet browsers would still figure it out. -->
<script type="text/javascript" fakeout="src=" oops="" src
                                                      ="http://example.com/oops.js">
    document.write("<script sr" + 'c="http://example.com/oops.js"></script>");
</script>
```

Now, if instead you're just trying to find all the externally-referenced scripts in a site you maintain (e.g., to see if a random script is still used), then many of the other answers will do.

Comment: interesting to know this, but im not doing this.

Comment: @Vanilla: It would help to know what you *are* doing. Also keep in mind that SO questions/answers are intended to help people who stumble across them in the future, so I think its important to explain this caveat.

Comment: I agree. A regex will be perfectly fine for scraping a bunch of your own files, but should never be used to sanitize against script injection.

Comment: Well, it can be troublesome for scraping your own files too, for example the missing closing quote can easily be a typo, and will lead the regexp to produce some quite interesting results.

Answer (score 0):

Use `src=".*?"` in replace and replace with empty string.

Answer (score -1):

Here's my stab at it:

```
s/\s*src="[^"]*"//
```

That one also removes any whitespace before the 'src' (via the '\s*').

Answer (score -1):

Solution using sed

```
sed 's/\(^.*\) src.*/\1>/'
<script type="text/javascript">
```